# How do I delete rows using row numbers in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 110 rows and two columns. I would like to perform two operations in R:

1. Delete the first 50 rows from original dataframe.
2. Delete next 51-110 rows from original dataframe.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Your second operation will delete the whole data set, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. Actually, I have to perform the analysis on the first 50 rows and then the next 60 rows. In both the cases, I have to delete from the original dataframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example how you can achieve this:

```
    a <- data.frame(1:110,1:110) # creating a dummy data.frame
    a[-(1:50),] # removing first 50 rows
    a[-(51:110),] # removing next 60 rows
```

Comment: Have you tested yur solution?

Comment: It does for me. What is your output?

Comment: In your code you are not deleting the lines because you are not inserting it back into a

Comment: There is no real deleting here because you are not inserting it back to `a`. If you just wanted to select from `a` by row index, you don't need to put `-` there. This answer is not answering on your question, but whatever you like.